# What does the "Failed to download" error mean when importing an API into SwaggerHub?

Tags: swaggerhub

I'm trying to import my OpenAPI JSON file, http://...../swagger/v2/swagger.json, into SwaggerHub but the import fails with this error:

[image]

The "Show Details" link shows:

> Details:
> Status: 403

I don't know where the error comes from because the URL is correct. What should I do to successfully import the API?

Comment: Is the file on the public internet or your local network? (SwaggerHub can only import from Internet.) Does your swagger.json file require authentication to access it? Try downloading the file to your computer then importing the local file instead of an URL.

Comment: It work now, I just download the json file then I imported it, thank you